# Android take snapshot by minicap,return files are all 0bytes

Tags: android, adb, android-debug

I'm trying to take snapshot on android by using minicap,

```
dipper:/ $ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/local/tmp /data/local/tmp/minicap -P 1080x2248@1080x2248/0 -s > /mnt/sdcard/test.png
```

It seems that it works, adb shell shows the info

```
dipper:/ $ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/local/tmp /data/local/tmp/minicap -P 1080x2248@1080x2248/0 -s > /mnt/sdcard/test.png
PID: 9914
INFO: Using projection 1080x2248@1080x2248/0
INFO: (external/MY_minicap/src/minicap_28.cpp:241) Creating SurfaceComposerClient
INFO: (external/MY_minicap/src/minicap_28.cpp:244) Performing SurfaceComposerClient init check
INFO: (external/MY_minicap/src/minicap_28.cpp:255) Creating virtual display
INFO: (external/MY_minicap/src/minicap_28.cpp:261) Creating buffer queue
INFO: (external/MY_minicap/src/minicap_28.cpp:264) Setting buffer options
INFO: (external/MY_minicap/src/minicap_28.cpp:268) Creating CPU consumer
INFO: (external/MY_minicap/src/minicap_28.cpp:272) Creating frame waiter
INFO: (external/MY_minicap/src/minicap_28.cpp:276) Publishing virtual display
INFO: (jni/minicap/JpgEncoder.cpp:64) Allocating 7365636 bytes for JPG encoder
dipper:/ $
```

HOWEVER
In the file explorer, i find that all pictures are empty with 0 bytes...
it seems that the snapshots are not saved properly
The Android SDK is 28

Comment: Please provide the version of minicap you are using and if it possible device. Are you testing over real device or emulator?

Comment: The mincap is arm64-v8a , minicap.so is for AndroidSDK 28, testing on real device

Comment: I don't know about "minicap". If you don't get any answers try to create an issue in the github repository. I think is here: https://github.com/openstf/minicap/issues. It you get an answer it would be great you would add the answer in your own post.